# Syncing / adding / removing events with iCloud Calendar

Tags: c#, calendar, icloud, icalendar, caldav

I've literally looked around the internet for over a week searching how to do this. iCloud don't provide an API / oAuth, I've seen some solutions on SO where they say use CALDAV, but businesses simply aren't using this route when connecting to iCloud, and doing it through c#.

[image: Example for iCloud calendar]

This clearly isn't the CALDAV route - most businesses connect directly to clients iCloud account... then do something. But that something isn't readily available ANYWHERE on the internet to my knowledge.

Maybe I'm wrong and it is CALDAV, but I don't think it is.

Sorry for what may seem like "a bad question" but it's been well over a week and I'm truly desperate.

Any advice on what to do with connecting to iCloud to syncing/ adding/removing events from iCloud would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: Hi - Thanks. I'm aware, but, I don't personally think saying "this is CALDAV", no this is done through this resource ____ is broad. I'm not asking for SO to code Google's algorithm for me, simply ask anyone who has dealt with iCloud syncing - and what method they'd use. No specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SO is quite possibly the 'coldest' community online, I had to spend another few days researching - and asking friends. For others seeking the answer to this question, this is how I have done it:

It is done through CalDAV, I used this https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net which got me half way there.

^ Woah, that was hard wasn't it?

Comment: Not cold, rather I'd say focused.  You are expected to research yourself, then ask a question if still needed.

Comment: Nope, just incredibly cold. It's common knowledge really. I mod the biggest SEO forum in the world - it's filled with warmth. The community here is pretty vile. A good resource to get out of sticky situations, but very unwelcoming. And to counter your point, I clearly stated I researched for weeks. There is no definitive answer on the internet for this.